# What can I do to print only the total value?

Tags: java, arrays

```
 public static void main(String []args){
     Random gen = new Random();
 int[] numbers = new int[6];
 int sum, product;
 for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++){
     int pick = gen.nextInt(10);
     numbers[i] = pick;
     sum = (numbers[1]+numbers[2]+numbers[3]+numbers[4]+numbers[5]);
     product = sum *2;
     System.out.println("Random number: " + numbers[i]);
     System.out.println("Product is: " + product);
 }
 }
```

It prints this:

- Random number:    0
- Product is: 0
- Random numbers:   8
- Product is: 16
- Random number is: 9
- Product is: 34
- Random number is: 3
- Product is 40
- Random number is: 9
- Product is 58

Which is fine, but I only want the total number, being 58. Something Simple :/ I'm new at this.

Comment: Put the `System.out.println` outside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ever you iterate through the loop you're invoking the System.out.println method, that's why you're getting all the output, you need to take the methods out of your for loop

**Delete these:**

```
System.out.println("Random number: " + numbers[i]);

System.out.println("Product is: " + product);
```

**Put this one outside the for loop:**

```
System.out.println("Product is: " + product);
```

Comment: It was that easy T_T. Thank you very much sir!

Comment: No problem dude

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following statements from the loop:

```
System.out.println("Random number: " + numbers[i]);
System.out.println("Product is: " + product);
```

And add the following outside the loop:

```
System.out.println("Product is: " + product);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get this `System.out.println("Product is: " + product);` out of your loop